# The Include method is missing on an EntityFramework Linq Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Models

```
public class CreamModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int? Type_Id { get; set; }

    public CreamTypeModel CreamType { get; set; }
}

public class CreamTypeModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext

```
internal class CreamEFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CreamTypeModel> CreamTypeModels { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CreamModel> CreamModels { get; set; }
}
```

SQL query

[image: enter code here]

Second table

[image]

In my repository I want to take the list of creams and their type using the `Include` method but it's missing.

In my last project, the same method was available and working but now it isn't.

```
public class CreamRepository : ICreamRepository
{
    private CreamEFDbContext context = new CreamEFDbContext();

    public IEnumerable<CreamModel> CreamList
    {
        get { return context.CreamModels.Include(x => x.CreamType); }//have red line
    }
}
```

The following images show what I have in my current project vs the old project where the `Include` method worked:

Current Project

[image]

Last Project

[image]

Comment: Please provide a concise description of the error, or, if there is none, what your expected output vs actual output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` is an extension method from the [QueryableExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.queryableextensions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) class in the EntityFramework DLL. So you need to add a using statement to `System.Data.Entity`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```